# TeXLive 2019 folder is not deleted when installing a new one

Tags: installing

I installed TeXLive in `/usr/local/texlive/2020`, but the `2019` folder is still there. Should I manually delete it?

Furthermore, I have to install many packages I installed in 2019. Why isn't there an update/upgrade option? Doing `tlmgr list --only-installed > installed_texlive_packages.txt` *annually* is really a pain.

Comment: you can delete it or keep it as you wish (I have texlive 2016,2017,2018,2019,2020 installed locally, and just delete the oldest ones if I need space for other things). There are tlmgr options to upgrade tl2019 to 2020 rather then install completely new (although a fresh install is usually recommended)

Comment: You don't have to delete it unless you need the space on your drive. I have lots of older texlive around.

Comment: And make sure the `PATH` environment variable is set correctly to use the new installation. Check with `which latex`, for example.

Comment: On your first quesiton: Deleting the old folder is up to you. Some people prefer to keep both the old and the new version around. On your second question: Do please check out the posting [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5001). By placing your personal packages in `TEXMFHOME`, you would have to do nothing special to make the visible to the latest vintage of TeXLive.